# get facebook user cover

Tags: php, facebook

i tried to do the request throw php sdk

```
https://graph.facebook.com/100002250727434/?fields=id,name,cover
```

And the response is

`array(2) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(15) "100002250727434"
  ["name"]=>
  string(33) "My Name"
}`

Is there any necessary scope for getting cover? I got the default only public_profile scope. Or there is another error in my request?

Comment: No - you do not need any additional permissions - the cover photo is part of a users public profile.

Comment: then why i didnt get the data? Whats wrong with my request?

Comment: The same answer i will get if i will delete cover from request.

Comment: Can you share the actual user id you are using?

Comment: done, btw i tried with anothers id's (random change some numbers), and i still get only the id and name in response

Comment: Ahh... this user does not have a cover photo defined :) Try it with a user id of `4` (that's Mark.Z :P )

Comment: the story is that i have to make my own avatar in the system, for the cropped facebook avatar i use the
https://graph.facebook.com/:id/?fields=picture.height(140).width(140)
request. And i get what i need, but i must to save and source of the facebook avatar image for reason if user would like to change the crop x-y factor

Comment: You i right thx, facebook could became more friendly if it will return null for example ))

Answer (score 1):

I assume there is no cover in the result because the user did not upload a cover.

I tried the same call with my own user and got the cover:

```
{
  "cover": {
    "id": "xxxxx",
    "offset_y": 0,
    "source": "xxxxx.jpg"
  },
  "id": "xxxxx"
}
```

No extra permission needed.

Comment: yes but i still can get it by hack :) i get from api that my large picture is 
https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/t1.0-1/p200x200/189720_101742183244139_7865800_n.jpg 
then i replaced first part of url and get my source 
http://sphotos-e.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/189720_101742183244139_7865800_n.jpg 
But i dont know how can i get it from api